# In human anatomy / biomechanics, what is the motion called when the arm swings sideways so the elbow moves in an arc of 90 degrees?

Tags: human-anatomy, bio-mechanics

In human anatomy / biomechanics, what is the motion called when the arm swings sideways so the elbow moves in an arc of 90 degrees?

So e.g. if a person was to elbow somebody behind them , or if somebody had their arm out and then swung it keeping it parallel with the floor.

Like in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOh2-4WWzEE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s humeral retroversion at a 90 degrees abduction angle with extended elbow and slightly internally rotated shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

Shoulder Horizontal Abduction/Adduction.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3xJDsJ_Nw4&ab_channel=InteractiveBiology

"the motion of bringing the arm across the chest is called shoulder or glenohumeral horizontal adduction. Glenohumeral horizontal adduction is demonstrated starting from 90? of shoulder flexion

with the arm slightly away from midline in abduction as seen from a front or anterior view."

Abduction would be away from the midline/body. i.e. the outward direction.

Adduction would be towards the midline  i.e. coming across/towards your body.

Starting and staying at 90 degree shoulder flexion.

Google shows this from oxfordreference.com

"Horizontal adduction
horizontal adduction (horizontal flexion)
Movement of the arm or thigh in the transverse plane from a lateral position to an anterior position. ..."

So it's also known as Horizontal flexion and horizontal extension.

as shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0JxEZ87W40&ab_channel=BlakeMartin